# Paperclip-ffmpeg error with styles for thumbnail when uploading video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using Paperclip 3.4 and Paperclip-ffmpeg 0.9.4.
Here is my code in video.rb:

```
has_attached_file :file,
                :url => '/:class/:id/:style.:extension', 
                :styles => { :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 } }, 
                :processors => [:ffmpeg], :swallow_stderr => false
```

When I try to upload a video, the error is

```
Command 'ffmpeg -ss 10 -i :source -y -vf scale=100:-1,pad=100:100:0:12.5:black -vframes 1 -f image2 :dest' returned 1. Expected 0
```

If I comment out or remove the styles line, the video is uploaded correctly. I tried changing the versions of the gems, to no avail.

Any pointers on why the styles hash is causing an issue?

**Edit**
Replacing '#' with '>' seems to solve the issue, but I am not sure what is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official paper clip gem [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation) (under the "Resizing options" section) you can found the following description:

```
Default behavior is to resize the image and maintain aspect ratio (i.e. the :medium version of a 300×150 image will be 200×100). Some commonly used options are:

trailing #, thumbnail will be centrally cropped, ensuring the requested dimensions.
trailing >, thumbnail will only be modified if it is currently larger requested dimensions. (i.e. the :small thumb for a 120×80 original image will be unchanged)
```

and as it is pointed there you can check for more options [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/).